# In C# what does it mean when you have a variable and an &?

Tags: c#, operators

Found some code online I was looking at to solve a problem, and I'm not exactly sure what it's doing where it says "(candidate & 1) == 0". candidate is an int.

```
 if ((candidate & 1) == 0)
            {
                if (candidate == 2)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's a bitwise operator https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator

Comment: `if ((candidate & 1) == 0)` is checking if `candidate` is odd or even, doing a bitwise `AND` operation

Answer (score 2):

It's the binary (bitwise) AND operator. In your case the `if` statement is checking whether the least significant bit is 1, or in other words, whether `candidate` is even:

Example using numbers 35 and 34:

```
35 & 1 = 0b100011 & 0b1 == 1 => odd
34 & 1 = 0b100010 & 0b1 == 0 => even
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator